# Objects in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML as below

```
<rootElement>
    <element1>data</element1>    
    <element2 attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2">
        <inner_element>2</inner_element>
    </element2>
</rootElement>
```

the mapping is as follows:

```
public class RootElement{
    @XmlElement(name = "element1")
    String elem1;
    @XmlElement(name = "element2")
    Element2 element2;
}

public class Element2{
    @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute1")
    String attr1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute2")
    String attr2;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    Object value;    
}
```

I want to allow the user to input value of any type (String, Integer, Double) in `<inner_element>`.

In Java, I am able to read the other elements `<element1>` & `<element2>` but, I am getting `value` as `null`. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: can you generate an XSD shema of the XML

Answer (score 1):

Try @XmlValue instead of @XmlAnyElement on an InnerElement class.
Also parse to String instead of Object

Comment: Does not work, I have put a field 

@XmlValue
Object value;

inside an InnerElement class. (getting errors)
But, whenever I put Integer/Double/String, it works as long as the data input is correct.

Comment: What values are allowed in that element? It sounds like you need to parse it to a String to accommodate any value and then parse it to a number manually if it is one

Comment: I wanted to allow values of types Integer, String, Double..

Will implement it using String, then cast back to appropriate type. Thanks.

Comment: string will take care of all type of types in xml i think .

Answer (score 0):

Using this XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="rootElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="element1"/>
                <xs:element name="element2">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:anyType" name="inner_element"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="attribute1"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="attribute2"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I generate these class

```
package com.test.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "element1",
    "element2"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "rootElement")
public class RootElement {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String element1;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected RootElement.Element2 element2;

    public String getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }

    public void setElement1(String value) {
        this.element1 = value;
    }

    public RootElement.Element2 getElement2() {
        return element2;
    }

    public void setElement2(RootElement.Element2 value) {
        this.element2 = value;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "innerElement"
    })
    public static class Element2 {

        @XmlElement(name = "inner_element", required = true)
        protected Object innerElement;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute1")
        protected String attribute1;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "attribute2")
        protected String attribute2;

        public Object getInnerElement() {
            return innerElement;
        }

        public void setInnerElement(Object value) {
            this.innerElement = value;
        }

        public String getAttribute1() {
            return attribute1;
        }

        public void setAttribute1(String value) {
            this.attribute1 = value;
        }

        public String getAttribute2() {
            return attribute2;
        }

        public void setAttribute2(String value) {
            this.attribute2 = value;
        }

    }

}
```

And this ObjectFactory Class

```
package com.test.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public RootElement createRootElement() {
        return new RootElement();
    }

    public RootElement.Element2 createRootElementElement2() {
        return new RootElement.Element2();
    }

}
```